# String comparison wildcard inside echo

Tags: linux, bash

I can do the following command to check for string `"abc"` inside `$s` with a asterisk as *string wilcard*

```
 if [[ $s == *"abc"* ]]; then echo 1; fi
```

But inside an `echo`, the asterisk works as *directory listing*.

```
echo [[ $s == *"abc"* ]]
```

How can I use the wildcard inside an echo as *string wildcard*? Expected output should be 1 if `s` contains `abc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax of the first line is `if <command>; then ...`, that is, the `[[` is being treated as a command (and it's a special built-in command that has its own unique wildcard rules).

The syntax of the second line, however, is *not* `echo <command>`. You can't give *any* commands to `echo` like that; it will just write out the `[[` and the `$s` as ordinary text parameters – no comparison is done and special wildcard rules aren't applied (not that they would be useful since no string comparison is done).

That is, it's basically like `echo ls /etc` – it won't `ls` anything, it'll just print the words "ls /etc".

If you want to make a string comparison outside `if`, you still need to run the `[[` as a separate command, checking or printing its return code via `$?`. For example:

```
[[ $s == *abc* ]]
echo "Result is $?"
```

Note that exit codes use `0` for success. If you want 1, use an `$(( ... ))` arithmetic expansion:

```
echo "Result is $(( ($? == 0) ? 1 : 0 ))"
echo "Result is $(( !$? ))"
```

If you *really* want it to be in a single command, you could cram it into a `$(...)` substitution:

```
echo $( [[ $s == *abc* ]]; echo $? )
```

...but that's literally the same as just doing `[[ $s == *abc* ]]; echo $?` in the first place.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to `[[ ! ... ]]`?

Comment: `!` and `!=` should be fine as well.